# Why is 遞 = (辶 + (厂 + 虎))?

Tags: characters, etymology, glyph-origin

**遞** is most commonly used, nowadays, to mean "to pass" -or- "to give".

Here's the definition of its simplified counterpart *递* given on [zisea](http://zisea.com/htm/90/9012.htm):

> ①传送，传达：传～。投～。～送。～交。～眼色（以目示意）。呈～国书。
>
> ②顺着次序：～补。～变。～增。～减。～升。～降。
>
> ③古代指驿车。

I can only see 遞 (辶 + (厂 + 虎)) as *the walking tiger factory*, which I'm sure is quite absurd, but even *虒* is defined, on [zisea](http://zisea.com/htm/86/8652.htm), again, as

> “委～”古书上说的一种似虎有角的兽。

in which case we have 遞 = 辶 + 虒, or *the moving sī*...

- Why is 遞 (meaning to give, to pass) = (辶 + (厂 + 虎))?
- Etymology?

Comment: 厂 doesn't actually mean factory as a radical, it just happened to come to mean this when simplified chinese made it a character on its own that meant this (traditional: 厰). It's also not usually worth taking chinese characters for their literal components. Some characters do work like this, such as 休, but almost 90% of characters are phono-semantic -- one part shows meaning while the other shows how to pronounce it (see cress' answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[说文解字：更易也。从辵虒聲。](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/sw/905E.htm)

Actually, 遞=辵+虒, it's a [pictophonetic character](http://www.chineselearner.com/writing/characters/pictophonetic.html) which original meaning is "to alternate".

The meaning radical(形旁) 辵 carries the basic meaning "to walk one moment and stop the next".

The sound radical(声旁) 虒 only indicates the pronunciation of 遞(dì).